# Downvotes in cryptocurrency posts

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that a few posts related to cryptocurrencies have constantly all the answers downvoted:

[This one from this week](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/18606/what-are-the-diferences-between-criptocurrencies-and-digital-currencies-backed-b) had a downvote for both answers, without comments (i upvoted the other user)

[This one](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/effects-of-decentralized-currency?rq=1) from May had a new user receiving a down vote without any comment

[This one](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/17741/how-are-cryptocurrencies-reported-in-gdp) from August received 1 down vote and 1 upvote.

**Is it just a coincidence, or is the community intentionally ignoring cryptocurrencies?**

I admit I am directly involved in many of these posts, and what frustrates me on this is the lack of feedback, not the downvote itself. Attitudes like this are likely to prevent growth in the community - the user in one of the posts above hasn't posted ever since.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions about *economic aspects* of cryptocurrencies should be welcome in principle.  As EnergyNumbers says it's a topic that can attract bad questions and bad answers, but there's no reason why it shouldn't attract good ones too.

Although the site doesn't require downvotes to be explained, comments with reasons for downvotes can sometimes be helpful, especially where posts have both good and bad features, eg to encourage editing to improve posts, and to draw readers' attention to errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the straight-to-the-point answers. I think at the end the three answers we received here represent different perspectives in the community, and I understand all points of view - which explains the reception of cryptocurrency questions clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Cryptocurrencies routinely attract bad questions and bad answers. Unsurprisingly, such ponzi schemes routinely attract people who are economically illiterate.

You've given some good examples. These should be downvoted - that's just as it should be.

Furthermore, downvotes are not required to be accompanied by comments. The tooltip over the down arrow gives the reasons for downvotes.

And finally, asking for comments from downvoters, in comments, is noise and clutter. Please stop doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I find that two out of these three questions are unclear, so I am definitely ignoring them. I don't think there is any trend.

I was the downvote on your answer on the third question. I have just read the edit made after my vote and I removed my vote.